# How can I click the "Home Folder" on dash to open another Nautilus explorer when there is one already opened?

Tags: unity, nautilus, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, and really satisfied with the Unity.

But there is one thing annoying me. If I click the Home Folder button on dash, and for example I want to copy some files from one folder to another. Then I click the Home folder again, but it will bring me to the previous folder not open a new Nautilus explorer for me.

And for the terminal, I can always press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a new window. So I'm asking, is there any shortcut or any way to achieve it?

Comment: You can always click File/New Window in your current open Nautilus window to open a second nautilus.

Answer (score 6):

Middle click on an icon in the unity dash to open a new instance of the program. This applies to nautilus also.